# How and why should I use Events and delegates

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I read about events and delegates. I think I understand how they work but I do not understand why should I use them.

For example, I have online shop where customer has balance and is buying products using this money.

This is enough to do the job.
When user buys something, sells something or deposits money - UserWallet class is called.

```
class Shop
{
    public static void BuyOrderFilled(){
        if(userHasBalance()){
            UserWallet userWallet = new UserWallet();
            userWallet.DeductMoney();
        }

        UpdateInventory();
    }

    public static void SellOrderFilled(){
        //Sell order has different logic
        if(userHasProduct()){
            UserWallet userWallet = new UserWallet();
            userWallet.RemoveProductFromUser();
        }

        UpdateInventory();
    }
}

class Deposit{
    public static void UserGotDeposit(decimal amount){
        UserWallet userWallet = new UserWallet();
        userWallet.FillUserBalance(amount);
    }
}

class UserWallet{
    public void DeductMoney(){
        //Some logic
    }
    public void RemoveProductFromUser(){
        //Some logic
    }
    public void FillUserBalance(){
        //Some logic
    }
}
public class Main(){
    Shop.BuyOrderFilled();
    Shop.SellOrderFilled();
    Deposit.UserGotDeposit(100);
}
```

Why should I use Events or delegates when I can just call UserWallet methods whenever I need them?

Comment: An event can be used if you want your code to notify other code that something interesting has happened, but you don't yet know what other code will want to know it, or what action should occur as a result. So a writer of a code library might use it. Obviously events are very common in user interface code - e.g. an event occurs when someone clicks a button or presses a key. But you can use them in dozens of other scenarios too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use them..

..it's just that sometimes it's super handy to be able to pass methods around like they were data.

Quite often the utility in this is if you're providing a library for other people to use and you want to make it useful for them but you don't know a thing about their code or how they'll use it. An obvious one is `List<T>` in the framework; you might be writing something like it and want to provide a way for people to search if, but you don't know what kind of objects they will put in the list or how they want to search for them.

If, however you just provide them with a method like `Find(delegate)` then it's a "method that takes a method as a parameter" - you declare to the user "provide Find with a method that takes a T and returns a boolean of true if it should be included in the search results", then it means they can write a method like this:

```
bool IsSmith(Person p) {
  return p.LastName == "Smith";
}
```

And they can pass it to your list Find method, your method runs their method, gives it the List object, gets a bool and decides what to do based on the result

```
var smiths = myListOfPeople.Find(IsSmith);
```

Nowadays we don't usually write the method out so long hand, we use the funky inline declaration where we just provide the parameter name and the logic, and the compiler inserts all the other stuff it can work out

```
var smiths = myListOfPeople.Find(p => p.LastName == "Smith");
```

In essence you can control every part of the process when you wrote your List class, you can implement the find, you can return the results - but in making your List truly flexible and letting people store what they want in it, you create a gap in the middle where you can't know how to search for a Whatever that the user put into it. Being able to let them pass a method in (of a known arguments type and return type) that you can call closes that gap

---

Another example; events this time but they're no different. An event is just a list of methods that the user of your class can fill with "bits of code that shall be run when something happens"

Take a button click: you want to download a file, your coworker wants to save an image, I want to calculate factors of a number entered in a text box.. We're all using that same Button class but we all want to do different things when we click our different buttons, so the easiest way for Microsoft to make the perfect button is to just leave that "do this when clicked" part for us to fill in, and that's done by having a way to associate a delegate (method passed round like a variable) with the button, and coding the button so that it runs the delegate when it's clicked, whatever the delegate may do

---

So all that is great for Microsoft, who create Buttons and Lists and other generic things for us to enjoy, but does it have a place for us in our own code? Sure, though more rare, I find it helpful to make some helper class for example- something that launches ffmpeg and reads from its output stream.. and mostly it's just nonsense but occasionally interesting messages are sent, so I might make an event that I raise when such a message is sent.. I use my helper in one project and I'm looking for dropped frames, in another I want to know if silence is detected.. In those cases I suppose the "person who provides the library to the person who consumes the library" was me at both ends. I have other projects where I want to perform similar tasks on different data, the writer routine is the same but the parsing is different; being able to pass a method to say how to pull a name out of this object but a number out of that one makes life a lot nicer than having some massive "if object is a person pull the name, else if object is a building pull the number and street" conditional block in a place it doesn't belong